# Distinct integer solutions to the equation $(x^2+y^2+z^2)/(x+y+z)=2n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I’ve been set this problem by my teacher, and had no idea where to start. I have a [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation):

$$
\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}=2n
$$

$x, y, z$ and $n$ must be distinct positive integers. I’ve found solutions where there is an equality for any of $x, y$ and $z$ but I haven’t been able to for distinct positive integers, and would appreciate help.

Comment: I think there is a problem in the formulation of your problem. One can prove that given some $n$ there are at most finitely many integer solutions $x$, $y$ and $z$. Maybe for some $n$ there is only one integer solution for $x$, $y$ and $z$?

Comment: I think you must mean that $x,y,$ and $z$ must be _distinct_ positive integers?

Answer (score 2):

This one is quite difficult; at least, difficult to find all primitive integer solutions and prove that we have all. Taking $a=x-n,b=y-n,c=z-n,$ we are led to
$$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 3n^2. $$
In order to get $\gcd(a,b,c,n)=1,$  it is necessary that all be odd.

I think I will leave in the zeros in the formulas for $a,b,c.$ They serve as spacers.
$$ n = p^2 + q^2 + r^2 + s^2 $$
$$ a = p^2 + q^2 - r^2 - s^2 + 0 \, p  q - 2  p  r + 2  q  r + 2  p  s + 2  q  s + 0  \,  r  s $$
$$ b = p^2 - q^2 + r^2 - s^2 + 2  p  q - 0  \,  p  r + 2  q  r - 2  p  s + 0  \,  q  s + 2  r  s$$
$$ c = p^2 - q^2 - r^2 + s^2 - 2  p  q + 2  p  r + 0  \,  q  r + 0  \,  p  s + 2  q  s + 2  r  s$$

In the table below, for each line just take the eight solutions $x=n \pm a, y=n \pm b,z=n \pm c.$ Some of those will have $x,y,z$ positive.

=========================

```
    n       x    y    z                                         p    q    r    s 
    1 ;     2    2    2 x^2+y^2+z^2: 12 x+y+z: 6 * 2n: 12 ;     1    0    0    0
    3 ;     8    4    4 x^2+y^2+z^2: 96 x+y+z: 16 * 2n: 96 ;     0    1   -1   -1
    5 ;    12   10    6 x^2+y^2+z^2: 280 x+y+z: 28 * 2n: 280 ;     0    1    0   -2
    7 ;    18   12    8 x^2+y^2+z^2: 532 x+y+z: 38 * 2n: 532 ;     1    2    1    1
    9 ;    20   20   10 x^2+y^2+z^2: 900 x+y+z: 50 * 2n: 900 ;     0    2    2    1
    9 ;    22   16   14 x^2+y^2+z^2: 936 x+y+z: 52 * 2n: 936 ;     0    2   -1   -2
   11 ;    24   24   16 x^2+y^2+z^2: 1408 x+y+z: 64 * 2n: 1408 ;     0    1    1   -3
   11 ;    28   18   16 x^2+y^2+z^2: 1364 x+y+z: 62 * 2n: 1364 ;     3    1    0    1
   11 ;    30   12   12 x^2+y^2+z^2: 1188 x+y+z: 54 * 2n: 1188 ;     3    0   -1    1
   13 ;    30   26   20 x^2+y^2+z^2: 1976 x+y+z: 76 * 2n: 1976 ;     0    2    0   -3
   13 ;    32   24   18 x^2+y^2+z^2: 1924 x+y+z: 74 * 2n: 1924 ;     2   -2   -2   -1
   15 ;    34   32   20 x^2+y^2+z^2: 2580 x+y+z: 86 * 2n: 2580 ;     3    2    1    1
   15 ;    38   26   20 x^2+y^2+z^2: 2520 x+y+z: 84 * 2n: 2520 ;     1   -1    3   -2
   15 ;    40   22   16 x^2+y^2+z^2: 2340 x+y+z: 78 * 2n: 2340 ;     1   -3   -2   -1
   17 ;    40   30   30 x^2+y^2+z^2: 3400 x+y+z: 100 * 2n: 3400 ;     0    3   -2   -2
   17 ;    40   34   24 x^2+y^2+z^2: 3332 x+y+z: 98 * 2n: 3332 ;     4    0   -1    0
   17 ;    42   28   28 x^2+y^2+z^2: 3332 x+y+z: 98 * 2n: 3332 ;     0    3    2    2
   17 ;    46   22   18 x^2+y^2+z^2: 2924 x+y+z: 86 * 2n: 2924 ;     3   -2   -2    0
   19 ;    42   42   24 x^2+y^2+z^2: 4104 x+y+z: 108 * 2n: 4104 ;     1   -3    3    0
   19 ;    44   36   32 x^2+y^2+z^2: 4256 x+y+z: 112 * 2n: 4256 ;     0    3   -1   -3
   19 ;    48   30   30 x^2+y^2+z^2: 4104 x+y+z: 108 * 2n: 4104 ;     1    0    3   -3
   19 ;    50   30   20 x^2+y^2+z^2: 3800 x+y+z: 100 * 2n: 3800 ;     1    1    1   -4
   21 ;    46   44   34 x^2+y^2+z^2: 5208 x+y+z: 124 * 2n: 5208 ;     0    2    1   -4
   21 ;    50   40   32 x^2+y^2+z^2: 5124 x+y+z: 122 * 2n: 5124 ;     2    3    2    2
   21 ;    52   40   22 x^2+y^2+z^2: 4788 x+y+z: 114 * 2n: 4788 ;     4    2    0    1
   23 ;    52   48   34 x^2+y^2+z^2: 6164 x+y+z: 134 * 2n: 6164 ;     1   -3   -3   -2
   23 ;    54   48   24 x^2+y^2+z^2: 5796 x+y+z: 126 * 2n: 5796 ;     3   -2   -3   -1
   23 ;    58   42   24 x^2+y^2+z^2: 5704 x+y+z: 124 * 2n: 5704 ;     1   -3    3    2
   23 ;    60   36   30 x^2+y^2+z^2: 5796 x+y+z: 126 * 2n: 5796 ;     3    3    1    2
   25 ;    56   50   42 x^2+y^2+z^2: 7400 x+y+z: 148 * 2n: 7400 ;     0    3    0   -4
   25 ;    60   44   42 x^2+y^2+z^2: 7300 x+y+z: 146 * 2n: 7300 ;     4   -2   -2   -1
   25 ;    60   48   36 x^2+y^2+z^2: 7200 x+y+z: 144 * 2n: 7200 ;     1   -2    4   -2
   25 ;    66   38   30 x^2+y^2+z^2: 6700 x+y+z: 134 * 2n: 6700 ;     1    4    2    2
   25 ;    68   30   26 x^2+y^2+z^2: 6200 x+y+z: 124 * 2n: 6200 ;     2   -1    4   -2
    n      x    y    z                                                p    q    r    s
```

==========================

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many non-trivial solutions $x=y=z$ with $x$ even and $n=\frac{x}{2}$:

$$
\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}=\frac{3x^2}{3x}=x=2n.
$$
So they cannot be unique.

Edit: The title now says *distinct* integer solutions (in the body it is still says *unique* integer solutions. In this case consider, for example,
$$
(x,y,z,n)=(18,12,8,7). 
$$
This solves your equation in *distinct* integers.

Answer (score -2):

Above equation shown below:
\begin{equation}
(x^2+y^2+z^2)/(x+y+z)=2n  \tag{A}
\end{equation}

Equation $(A)$ has parametric solution:

$x=b(a+b)$

$y=a(7a+b)$

$z=2ab$

$n=(1/2)*(7a^2-2ab+b^2)$

For $(a,b)=(1,17)$ we get:

$(x,y,z,n)= (306,24,34,131)$

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for your answer and welcome to the forum. I'm sorry to tell you that your answer is not useful, because you have no development and any important explication in your answer.